# Transforming 1D Burgers' Equation into infinitely many coupled ODE's

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, transformation, nonlinear-system

I've been working on the following problem but I can't justify my steps, would a savvy  mathematician kindly tell me what, if any, violations I've made.

Problem: Show Burgers' equation can be written as a system of infinitely many coupled ODE's. $$u_t+uu_x=\nu u_{xx}$$ and $$ \hat u_n=\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\substack{-\pi\\}}^\pi u(x,t)e^{-ikx}dx$$ is the $n^{th}$ Fourier coefficient of $u(x,t)$. The boundaries are periodic.

First, I Fourier transform the equation to $$ \frac{d\hat u}{dt}-i\omega^2g(n) \hat u-\omega^2\nu \hat u =0$$
Next, I rewrite the Fourier transform of $u$ which I think takes care of the periodic boundary conditions by writing it as an infinite sum...this move feels sketchy:
$$\hat u=\frac{1}{2\pi} \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty u(x,t)e^{-inx}$$
I then rewrite the Fourier transformed equation in terms of the infinite sums,  where I cancel out the $\frac{e^{-inx}}{2\pi}$ terms and move the sum outside of everything to get
$$ \sum\limits_{n=-\infty}^\infty (\frac{du}{dt}-u\omega^2(ig_n-\nu)=0)$$
which looks like a system of infinitely many coupled ODE's...but I would appreciate insight into whether it's mathematically correct or just plain wrong.

Comment: What are $g(n)$ and $g_n$?

Comment: I read that the fourier transform of a function multiplied by itself is the fourier transform of that function multiplied by a new function. So g is the new function and I labeled them as g(n) (continuous) and g_n (discrete)

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification.  Thinking . . . Cheers!